# Can an awaitable task be assigned to an action?

Tags: c#, asynchronous

I have an Action defined as:

```
Action CurrentDxList;
```

Originally, I was using it as:

```
private void test()
{
 CurrentDxList = MakeAllDxList;
 CurrentDxList();
}
```

where

```
private void MakeAllDxList()
        {
            var dx = MedicalClient.GetAllDx((int)Patient.Patient_Recid, Patient.tservice);
            _dxlist = dx.OrderBy(o => o.Cdesc);

            DxList = new ObservableCollection<DiagnosisDetail>(iDxDetail);
            ListCount = DxList.Count();
        }
```

However, MakeAllDxList() is better defined with async as:

```
private async Task MakeAllDxList()
        {
            var dx = await MedicalClient.GetAllDxAsync((int)Patient.Patient_Recid, Patient.tservice);
            _dxlist = dx.OrderBy(o => o.Cdesc);

            DxList = new ObservableCollection<DiagnosisDetail>(iDxDetail);
            ListCount = DxList.Count();
        }
```

Which now leads to the following error:

> Task MakeAllDxList() has the wrong return type.

So is it possible to assign an awaitable to an action? How is this done? Any ideas are most welcome.

Ofcourse, I could change the signature of MakeAllDxList() to

```
private async void MakeAllDxList()
```

but then I would lose all the advantages of async Task.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to change the `Action` to a `Func<Task>`, that is the new type definition.

P.S. Don't forget to await the `CurrentDxList` delegate

```
private async Task test()
{
 CurrentDxList = MakeAllDxList;
 await CurrentDxList();
}
```

You will need to update whoever calls `test` to be async too.

Comment: Works great. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
private async Task MakeAllDxList()
    {
        var dx = await MedicalClient.GetAllDxAsync((int)Patient.Patient_Recid, Patient.tservice);
```

In the code above the "var dx = await" pattern is called a closure. If you set the break point to the first line of code after that statement you would see the value of dx to be of the type returned by the GetAllDxAsync method.  Because the method is named "Getxyz" that implies it is reutrning data of some type.  To get out of your MakeAllDxList method, two things need to happen 1) Change the return type of Task, to `Task<dxType>` where dxType is the type of the variable dx.  2) After the var dx line, put in a statement of "return dx".

Comment: I have never seen `var dx = await` called a closure before. Normally when talking closures it is with lambada statements `xyz => ...`

Comment: I called it that  because of this construct which happens in almost all my programs due to my style.  var x = await Task<string>.Run(()=>{ return GetSomething();}  Technically it's not a closure (or is it?), but I'm wondering if there's a better name?  This I know, if we use that style, then the Task is magically unwrapped for the caller (to not have to deal explicitly with the Task.Result).  Maybe we could call it "Unwrapping the Task.Result"?